# Swiper Angular Pagination issue with Virtual Scroll

Tags: javascript, css, angular, ionic-framework, swiper.js

I have a feed like feature inside Angular and I am using swiper to show the images for each product, I am also using the cdk virtual scroll of angular.

This is how it roughly looks like:

```
<cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport itemSize="649" class="scrollable" scrollDetect (scrolled)="onScroll($event)" #scrollableContainer id="scrollsableContainer" [class.disable-scroll]="disableScroll">

    <div class="product" *cdkVirtualFor="let product of fetchedData; let f = index; trackBy: trackByProductId;" id="{{'product-'+f}}" >

        <div class="prod-pics" style="z-index: 998" (click)="$event.stopPropagation();" *ngIf="product.picUrl">
        
          <swiper-container (swiper)="onSwiper($event)" observer="true" observeParents="true" slidesPerView="auto" [pagination]="true" pagination-dynamic-bullets="true" style="--swiper-pagination-color: white; --swiper-pagination-bullet-inactive-color: white" *ngIf="product.picUrl">

                <swiper-slide *ngFor="let media of product?.picUrl; trackBy: trackByIda " >
                  <img [src]="media" alt="Product Image" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; object-fit: cover;" loading="lazy">
                </swiper-slide>

          </swiper-container>
        
      </div>

</div

</cdk-virtual-scroll-viewport>
```

It's all fun and games and it works if I have swiper-container set to 85vw.

Once I set this to 100vw, the entire pagination gets bugged, I scroll far down while the first product has 5 images and it initially displayed 5 dots and was able to swipe back and forth, I scroll down then scroll back up and then suddenly it only has 3 dots, all the pagination gets mixed up .etc

I've tried everything nothing is working and I have no clue what is causing this, literally if I set the swiper-container to 85vw it works like a charm, but 86vw doesnt for example, 84vw doesnt work either, 100vw doesn't, why is it specific to 85vw I am not understanding what is happening here ???

Any help would be appreciated